# 'generator' object has no attribute 'is_expression_type'

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo, operations-research

I am using pyomo to model a problem and am having some difficulty in constructing a constraint using data from a block. I have the block all set to go, totally debugged. When I go to access some of the data from it as part of a constraint, I receive an error, saying `'generator' object has no attribute 'is_expression_type'`

The block I have set up is:

```
def block_variables(block, j):
    demand_data = data['demand_data']
    supply_data = data['supply_data']
    I = block.model().I
    J = block.model().J
    G = block.model().G
    model.quantity_demanded = pe.Param(J, initialize = demand_data["quantity_demanded"])
    block.shipping_cost = pe.Param(J, initialize = demand_data["shipping_cost"])
    block.max_supply = pe.Param(I, initialize = supply_data['max_supply'])
    block.x = pe.Var(I, domain = pe.NonNegativeIntegers)
    block.per_unit_costs = pe.Param(I, initialize = supply_data["per_unit_cost"])
    block.fixed_costs = pe.Param(I, initialize = supply_data["fixed_cost"])
    block.variable_costs = sum(block.per_unit_costs[i][g] * block.x[i] for g in G for i in I)
```

The line in question is as follows:

```
def constraint_maximum_supply(model, i):
    return sum(model.block_variables.x[i]) \
        <= (model.block_variables[i].max_supply[j] * model.decision[i] for j in model.J)
model.constraint_maximum_supply = pe.Constraint(model.I, rule = constraint_maximum_supply)
```

I have watched the [UT Austin INFORMS video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T5LjmbyA1o0&ab_channel=UTAustinINFORMSStudentChapter) on this subject several times, and with his constraint he seems to have indexed the block by j, or `model.block_variables[j].x[i] for j in model.J` When I went about trying this, I received the error `"Cannot treat the scalar component 'block_variables' as an indexed component."` I do note that there are some differences in the way we construct our blocks, but I don't understand quite how that would cause this error.

Any help that can be offered would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much for taking the time to read as well.

Answer (score 0):

This part of your "problem line" is the problem...

```
(model.block_variables[i].max_supply[j] * model.decision[i] for j in model.J)
```

You have parenthesis around this, which turns it into a generator with the for-loop inside of it, but you don't have a `sum` in front of this.  Is that what you intended?  Something like this

```
... sum(model.block_variables[i].max_supply[j] * model.decision[i] for j in model.J)
```

`pyomo` is telling you that the "generator" you have here cannot be interpreted as a legal `pyomo` expression.